# Using data across all pages

Tags: node.js, rendering, ejs

I have assigned values to the keys, cart and subtotal. But I want to use the data across all pages rather than just the cart page. Is there a way to render it to all my pages as you always have to specify only one path in the res.render function? Example below.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  let cart = req.session.cart;
  let subtotal = req.session.subtotal;

    res.render('cart', {cart:cart, subtotal:subtotal})
})
```

I want to use the values of cart and subtotal across all my pages. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Persist the data somehow, like in a session, and retrieve it from the store whenever you need to render it.

Comment: Can you explain this further? I am fairly new to this

Comment: Try out a tutorial on https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session